# What does it mean to sample a clock?

Tags: fpga

I have to sample an external clock with a faster FPGA internal clock. The main issue here is that I initially thought it could be easily done with something like:

```
always @(fast_clk)                  // fast_clk is the internal clock
    slow_clk_dl <= slow_clk         //slow_clk is the external clock
```

But it appears it can't. The reason for this is that after simulating such a signal, I realized that since the two clocks are not synchronized, the sampled output had its duty cycle changed. 
What does it mean to sample a clock with another clock? I would appreciate it if you could provide a sample code snippet to explain. Thank you.

Comment: What is your goal in quantization of the Clock.  PWM? frequency and phase?  What is your tolerance error budget?  Can you think of a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If besides the clock you have some signals to sample as well, you have what is called a *clock boundary crossing*. There are various techniques for doing this reliably. Most often it involves the use of a FIFO with two clocks, with handshake logic between the FIFO ports specially designed to be resampled into each clock domain (for example, using Gray code FIFO counts.)

More about this here: https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276114#

And here: http://www.ece.utep.edu/courses/web5375/Notes_files/ee5375_asynch.pdf

And here: http://www.fpga-faq.com/FAQ_Pages/cdc_wp.pdf

If you are only sampling a clock signal, your sampling clock needs to be at least 2x the input clock rate (that is, the Nyquist limit) to capture all the state transitions. As a practical matter the sampling clock will need to be even higher than Nyquist rate to account for less than perfect 50% input duty cycle: your sample clock period has to be no less than your shortest input clock high or clock low period.

Finally, part of clock domain crossing is the inevitable issue of metastability: the failure of a sampling flip-flop to properly resolve to a valid state because its input sample/hold timing isn't being met. Using two flop stages will reduce failures to acceptable levels in most cases.

More about metastability here: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01082-quartus-ii-metastability.pdf

Now, what happens to the duty cycle of the re-sampled clock? It will vary depending on the frequency ratio and cycle-by-cycle phase relationship of the two clocks. You will need to account for that in your logic, for example by using edge detection.

Comment: all the edges?  it's asynchronous and edge ambiguity is 50%

Comment: Extreme oversampling often captures edges with much less ambiguity. Many asynchronous receivers use this trick to lock onto asynchronous data.

Comment: I think in the context of the original post, that’s an esoteric point. Even then, a system like that will use some sort of clock recovery PLL/DLL and... a FIFO. So it’s a clock boundary cross.

Comment: Hello @hacktastical. Thank you very much for your explanation. I guess it is befitting to say my life has been changed :D. Anyway, when you say that I should use edge detection to account for the phase shifts that result in varying duty cycles of the sampled signal, what do you mean? Which signal's edge should I look to edge detect and why? (FYI) I know how to edge detect.

Comment: You will want to detect a 0-to-1 or a 1-to-0 transition to reliably detect the occurrence of a new clock cycle. This is because your resampled clock will not have a consistent number of high and low states. So if, for example, your clock sampled as 0-0-1-1-0-0-0, you'd detect the '0-1' sequence as a new 'cycle' of your clock.

Comment: Hello, @hacktastical, If I detect only the edges, wouldn't that produce the same waveform? So as you said for; 0-0-1-1-0-0-0, two pulses goes high at a 1-0 / 0-1 transition. This to me, means that the duty cycle would not change. Maybe I am seeing wrongly, please help me out.

Comment: You’re detecting changes of state, not edges.

Comment: okay, I got it. Thanks a lot for the help.